# Modify vfs transport to use my own transfer protocol

Tags: wso2, apache-commons-vfs

Is it possible to modify the vfs transport in wso2 esb to used my own file transfer protocol? I have no idea to do this, I tried to search about this but I found no documentation about how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own transport and plug into esb. WSO2 ESB uses Axis2 Transports and following resources will help, but you have to play with code to get it done. http://synapse.apache.org/transports.html
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/transports/docs_index.html